# Какой шрифт используются в калькуляторе Windows 10?

Tags: windows, шрифты

Какое семейство шрифтов и размер шрифта используются в стандартном калькуляторе Windows 10?

Comment: Используемые TTF-файлы шрифтов конкретного процесса легко посмотреть через ProcessExplorer (https://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sysinternals/processexplorer.aspx) в Lower Pane - Handles. А там уже и до названия семейства или конкретного шрифта недалеко...

Comment: @Akina Спасибо, и правда интересная штука.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cкорее всего это **`Segoe UI`**

Источник можно найти [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13258287/what-font-is-used-on-most-microsoft-made-windows-8-apps).

Comment: Спасибо, вроде он. Пока ждал ответ, наткнулся на [документацию](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/uwp/design/style/segoe-ui-symbol-font), включающую коды символов системы, может кому-то пригодится.

Comment: Думаю это полезная информация, и полезный вопрос.